# Switched exchange servers, kept the same e-mail but some incoming mail is still going to the old server

Tags: email, exchange-server

I recently switched from an axoim exchange mail server to microsoft 365 exchange server. Now my email address is still the exact same as it was, and most of the incoming mail comes to my new server and address, but it looks like some incoming mail is still going to the old server. Why is that and what can i do to address it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you changed the MX records for your domain, so that they now point to Microsoft 365's mail servers, correct?  If so, it may take a day or two for the DNS changes to propagate.